# Cocos Typescript Error Global variable cc was dropped since 3.0. Use ES6 module syntax to import Cocos Creator APIs

Tags: typescript, cocos2d-js

I am new to Cocos Creator and I only found one Tutorial on Youtube for 2d Movement. And in this tutorial (In the docs of Cocos too) they always use `cc` but I got this Error:

> Global variable cc was dropped since 3.0. Use ES6 module syntax to import Cocos Creator APIs. e.G. "cc.macro.KEY.left:".

Can someone help me with this Typescript Error? Please don't give me links to the docs; I already looked at them.

Comment: Share a code snippet of your attempted fix. Also, this doesn't seem like a Typescript error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.